# Optaplanner swing application - webservice equivalent

Tags: rest, web-services, optaplanner

Is there any webservice equivalent of the example applications exposed in optaplanner like Roastering, Task Assigning?

Is there a way to integrate the existing optaplanner swing applications with a webservice(preferably REST)?

Comment: *"Is there a way to integrate the existing .. swing applications with a webservice..?"* Not embedded in a browser, as the applet tag implies. Oracle has deprecated applets (as well as the plug-in which launches them) and browser manufacturers no longer support loading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this guide on how to expose OptaPlanner as a REST service with Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner).

See also the accompanying source code with that guide and [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqTuRiWGLZQ).